# PGF equivalent of PostScript relative movement (`rlineto` and `rmoveto`)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-path

Like PostScript (with its `rmoveto` and `rlineto`), TikZ makes it trivial to produce relative movement of the current point. I'm not seeing anything equivalent in PGF.  Is it missing?  If so, is it easy to say why?  (And what is the intended replacement in PFG?)  Even if relative movement is not low-level enough for the system layer (hard to believe?), it seems low level enough for the base layer.

*Edit (Related Queries):* Is `\pgfrelative` deprecated (it's not in the current manual)? And, what PGF command produces the current point?

Comment: `\pgfpathmoveto` and `\pgfpathlineto`?

Comment: @noncommercial I'm not understanding. How does one use these for *relative* movement (dx,dy), without doing the x + dx, y + dy calculations oneself?

Comment: The coordinates are stored in `\pgf@x` and so on, and you can use `\pgfpointadd` to add points, e.g. `\pgflineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgflinewidth}{0}}}`. I probably do not understand the question.

Comment: `\pgfrelative` is deprecated. In [`pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty), you can see `\let\pgfrelative=\pgfpointadd`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Got it. Thanks! Do you know why `PGF` does not include coordinate changes *relative* to the current point? Coming from PostScript, it seems a very odd lack.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is `rmoveto` or `rlineto` in PDF. Since PDF is the de facto *backend* of PGF, both having `r`-counterparts and not having `r`-counterparts make sense to me.

Comment: @Symbol1 But I am asking about the base layer, not the system layer.

Comment: What I meant to say is ... since basic layer commands will be translated into system layer commands more or less "literally", it will "break the literality" if all but two commands do not map to system layer primitives. Plus, as @a--g pointed out, you got a more powerful `\pgfpointadd` to add two arbitrary points per your demand; so why bother with the limited `r`-edition? For the Ti*k*Z layer, the syntax is IMHO less expressive and more buggy. You cannot easily do `(F1, 0)--(F2, 0)--(F3, 0)--..` where Fn are the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @Symbol1 
1. I do not think the base layer is so bound to the system layer: consider `\pgfpathsine`.
2. `\pgflineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}{\pt}}` is a pretty long spelling of what could be `\pgfrlineto{\pt}`.
3. Coming from PostScript (and TikZ!), I can say that relative movement is very often useful.

Comment: @abcdefg Is `\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast` the best counterpart to PostScript's `currentpoint`? I would have expected `\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast`.

Comment: @Alan This was just taken from some decoration. So the answer is: it depends. If you are talking about decorations, the answer is yes, if not, then there are other constructions.

Comment: @abcdefg OK, that's probably why it's not working for me. What is the equivalent of `currentpoint` for ordinary path construction? Thanks.

Comment: @Alan As I said, it depends. In Ti*k*Z/pgf there are a lot of transformations going on. So even if you have the coordinates of the point when it was created, these coordinates may be off if you want to use them afterwards. For instance, in decorations Ti*k*Z transforms to tangent space. (This transformation gets inverted, which is why you can cure a lot of `dimension too large` errors by installing an `fpu` reciprocal.)

Answer (score 2):

In the following example, two new macros `\pgfpathrlineto{<coord>}` and `\pgfpathrmoveto{<coord>}` are provided. They are not fully tested, so be careful.

Actually, we need to keep track of the original (un-transformed) coordinates of last point, but here `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` store transformed coordinates.

The point is, in `(x, y) -- ++(2, 3)`, the expected line before transforming is `(x, y) -- (x+2, y+3)`, while what I implemented in the following example is `(x, y) -- ($ (x, y) + T'(2, 3) $)`, where `T'` is the inversion of transformation.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\makeatletter
\def\pgf@path@last@point{%
  \pgfpoint{\pgf@path@lastx}{\pgf@path@lasty}}

% rlineto
\def\pgfpathrlineto#1{%
  \pgf@process{#1}%
  \global\advance\pgf@x\pgf@path@lastx
  \global\advance\pgf@y\pgf@path@lasty
  % similar to \pgfpathlineto, but without applying transformation
  \pgf@nlt@lineto{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
  \global\pgf@path@lastx=\pgf@x
  \global\pgf@path@lasty=\pgf@y
}

% rmoveto
\def\pgfpathrmoveto#1{%
  \pgf@process{#1}%
  \global\advance\pgf@x\pgf@path@lastx
  \global\advance\pgf@y\pgf@path@lasty
  % similar to \pgfpathlineto, but without applying transformation
  \pgf@nlt@moveto{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
  \global\pgf@path@lastx=\pgf@x
  \global\pgf@path@lasty=\pgf@y
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{20pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{40pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{60pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}
  
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{10pt}{10pt}}
  \pgfsetcolor{red}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{20pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{40pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{60pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}
\end{pgfpicture}
\qquad
% use r(line|move)to
\begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathrlineto{\pgfpoint{20pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathrmoveto{\pgfpoint{20pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathrlineto{\pgfpoint{20pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}
  
  \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{10pt}{10pt}}
  \pgfsetcolor{red}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathrlineto{\pgfpoint{20pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathrmoveto{\pgfpoint{20pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathrlineto{\pgfpoint{20pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add comments to compare with the proposal of @abcdefg in the comments? Thanks.